# Split a string cell array based upon a delimiter

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a string cellarray something like this

```
12:34
13:45
12:45
```

Now I want to split this cell array into two with values separated by the delimiter. Something like this

The first one

```
12
13
12
```

and the second one

```
34
45
45
```

How can I do this in matlab?

Answer (score 4):

Input string cell array -

```
str_cellarr ={
    '12:34'
    '13:45'
    '12:45'}
```

Convert to a cell array with each cell having a `1x2` cell of split strings -

```
split1 = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x,':'), str_cellarr(:),'uni',0)
```

Or use a more efficient solution on this as suggested by @Luis -

```
split1 = regexp(str_cellarr, ':', 'split')
```

After this you can employ two approaches.

**Approach #1**

Convert to a `2 element` cell array with each cell containing each "set" of strings separated by the delimiter `':'` -

```
split1_2cols = mat2cell(vertcat(split1{:}),size(str_cellarr,1),[1 1])
```

Finally, store each set into separate variables as the final outputs -

```
[var1,var2] = deal(split1_2cols{:})
```

**Approach #2**

Use each column from `split1` array to get each set and store them as separate variables -

```
var1 = arrayfun(@(n) split1{n}(1),1:size(str_cellarr,1))' %//'
var2 = arrayfun(@(n) split1{n}(2),1:size(str_cellarr,1))' %//'
```

If you were looking to get char arary outputs, use `char(..)` to get those.

Comment: A little simpler: `split1 = regexp(str_cellarr, ':', 'split');`

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're dealing with time. Means `hours:minutes`.

In that case, the easiest would be to use the [**`datevec`**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/datevec.html) function, which is made for this purpose.

```
str = { '12:34'
        '13:45'
        '12:45'};

[~, ~, ~, H, M] = datevec(str,'HH:MM')
```

returns:

```
H =
    12
    13
    12


M =
    34
    45
    45
```

If you have `minutes:seconds` it works equally:

```
[~, ~, ~, ~, M, S] = datevec(str,'MM:SS')
```

If you further need strings, push everything through `num2str`, e.g.:

```
MinutesAsString = num2str(M);
```